# Selenium : Stop page loading

Tags: java, python, firefox, selenium

I am using Selenium to test a bunch of URLs. But some of those are not valid and the browser may take quite a lot of time to stop loading.
The `set_page_load_timeout(`) works well and will continue the execution of the code if the timeout has been reached but the next URL won't be tested until the browser has finished with its previous work... 
I also tried to send a Javascript code (`window.stop()`) but it does not work until the page has been loaded.

Is there any proper way to do this ?
If not, I will try any proposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly that by "they're not valid" you mean they may not exist, why not try:

```
 try {
     URL myURL = new URL("http://test.com/");
     URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
     myURLConnection.connect(); 
}  catch (MalformedURLException e) {  }  
catch (IOException e) {    //end test }
```

Comment: I just added myURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeout) and it does exactly what I want, thanks. I guess my mind was too focused on WebDriver...

Comment: Now that I think about it, this solution works but can be inefficient, if there is a load balancer, this can lead to incorrect results.